# First nodejs app, it is saying to update your less-middleware usage

Tags: node.js, express

I installed nodejs using homebrew just now.

I then created a folder, and installed express:

```
npm install -g express
```

I then created a new project using:

```
express -H --css less --sessions foo
```

Now when I try and run the app:

```
node app.js
```

I get this:

```
/Users/blah/dev/testing/nodetest1/foo/node_modules/less-middleware/lib/middleware.js:50
    throw new Error('Please update your less-middleware usage: http://goo.gl/Y
          ^
Error: Please update your less-middleware usage: http://goo.gl/YnK8p0
    at module.exports.less.middleware (/Users/blah/dev/testing/nodetest1/foo/node_modules/less-middleware/lib/middleware.js:50:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/snad/dev/testing/nodetest1/foo/app.js:26:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

My app.js looks like:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: path.join(__dirname, 'public') }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: The link it gave you explains it all: http://goo.gl/YnK8p0

Comment: I'm confused though, I didn't migrate anything it's all new?

Comment: The error is in your app code. At some point you've used 0.1.x style code instead of the newer 0.2.x code. Read through the page linked in the error and check that `app.js` conforms to the changes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I changed the line that was:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: path.join(__dirname, 'public') }));
```

to:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and it works now.  Strange how this was a brand new app with a fresh install of nodejs and express.

Comment: Vow! I had been bending my mind over it for so long!

Comment: same thing here. worked for me. they should update express generator

Comment: It's nice to give back to the community :)  your welcome newcomers to nodejs!

Comment: Even more odd is that the repo also doesn't show this new usage. https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware

Answer (score 0):

I commented out

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: path.join(__dirname, 'public') }));
```

entirely and achieved the same result. I feel that we are breaking functionality of some sort.

Comment: Commenting that line out will disable a runtime compiler for LESS files. This is fine if you're not using less or you prefer to compile your less files some other way.